# Does using html5shiv limits javascript usage in page?

Tags: javascript, html5shiv

I want to use **html5shiv** library. My website has many pages that include javascript code. Some page even have: `window.onload = new function() { ... }`

Do you think that the **html5shiv** disrupt disrupt the page's javascript functionality?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it just makes older browsers recognize certain elements

Comment: No, not at all. All it does is make IE “know” the HTML5 elements by creating them with `createElement` – and then throwing them away straight away again.

Comment: @Joe - your question is just an open-ended one with just a yes/no answer. And all it actually takes to derive is 10 minutes to setup the code and check if it works. What is encouraged is you finding an actual issue when you implement Html5Shiv and then posting a question about it.